# Aligning two lists within a row in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Now I know this is probably super simple, easy and obvious, but I've been banging my head for two days to try and figure this out. Googled up a storm.

I'm trying to align links within two lists at the bottom of a page to make a navbar. I'm using bootstrap and font awesome for icons. It seems as though the font awesome icons are larger than the font I'm using and causing misalignment.

You can see my problem here via codepen (its most noticeable in full screen mode or via a mobile device):

```
<http://codepen.io/alexwilson/pen/mAJqWX?editors=1100>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/383177a704.js"></script>
    <title>Alex Wilson - Man, Web Designer, Legend</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row headline">
        </div>

            <div class="row">
                    <ul id="list-left">
                        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
            </ul>
                        <ul id="list-right">
                            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexwilson33"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://github.com/AWilso30"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/XZISTTT"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/djcastaway"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="email.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html,
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.headline {
  height: 94%;
  background: url(http://www.desktopimages.org/pictures/2014/1025/1/orig_58711.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}
.row a {
  color: black;
}
.row a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.row a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.row a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}

.row a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.row ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#list-left {
  font-size: 3vh;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#list-right {
  font-size: 3vh;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

In the bottom navbar I'm attempting to create, it looks like the icons on the right are placed higher than the text links on the left.

Keep in mind I want everything to be responsive which is why I've set the font-size to vh.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can make the left links be vertically aligned with the right icons?

I've tried setting font-size smaller for the icons than for the left links, I've tried making two columns of xs-6 in bootstrap, I've tried messing around with padding and margin for divs and for the ul's themselves and more. So far nothing has worked right.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try vertical-align:top?

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question itself, Providng a codepen is good, but not enough

Comment: Ok. I've included the code. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I threw some unnecessary stuff out hope this helps.

```css
/*<!-- 
nest all nav?? 
color nav and links
make nav and links larger
make bg image slightly smaller
crop top of bg image to fit bottom
add padding to bg image
new font
larger nav
-->*/

body {
  background: url(http://www.desktopimages.org/pictures/2014/1025/1/orig_58711.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.row {
  margin:0 !important;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.row a {
  color: black;
}
.row a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.row a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.row a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}
.row a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.row ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.row li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#list-left,
#list-right {
  font-size: 3vh;
  line-height: 6vh;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/383177a704.js"></script>
  <title>Alex Wilson - Man, Web Designer, Legend</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <ul id="list-left">
      <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="work.html">Work</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list-right">
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexwilson33"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://github.com/AWilso30"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/XZISTTT"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/djcastaway"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="email.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow. Looks perfect. Thank you so much! So, correct me if I'm wrong, but you just removed the container-fluid and some unnecessary divs. Then to fix the difference in size you popped in a font size and line height to the right hand side of the list. Is that correct? I still don't understand why it didn't work before as most of what I read told me to wrap everything in a container with bootstrap. Can you please elaborate on why this works and the previous code did not?

Comment: For the first part yes font size and bigger line height automatically centers it. Also i inspected your version and it seems your bar wasn't quite at the bottom now with position fixed and bottom 0 it sticks there. :)

Comment: i would appreciate if you could mark that my answer helped you :)